# Reactjs "No routes match location "/blabla"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to keep the routes of the pages in separate components and render them in app.js, but it gives a "No routes match location" warning. I'm viewing the page I want but the warning is always there.

App.js:

```
<div id="app">
 <BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
   <HomeRoutes />
  </Routes>
 </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

HomeRoutes.js

```
<>
 <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
</>
```

Comment: Please share proper code snippet. Without it nobody can help you

Comment: I added the code snippets

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

exact when true, will only match if the path matches the location.pathname exactly

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

Comment: it only works when there is a route.


<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
<Route path="/"login element={<Login />} />

but in this case the same warning persists.

Comment: what do you get when you also apply exact to path="/login" ?

Comment: Happy to help. I am not so much good when it comes to react-router. I am still learning. You should probably also check documentation just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm uncertain why an other answer saying to use an `exact` prop was accepted as `react-router-dom@6` `Route` components have no `exact` prop.

[Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

The issue I see when running your code is that `[HomeRoutes] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`.

Only `Route` or `React.Fragment` are valid children of the `Routes` component, and only `Routes` or another `Route` component are valid parents of a `Route` component.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/*" element={<HomeRoutes />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

HomeRoutes - routes are rendered into a `Routes` component

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit reactjs-no-routes-match-location-blabla]